# How do I delete old values from my dynamodb via lambda function? Dates are timestamped in attribute names

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

[Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKsEt.png)

I started trying something like that to read the table values but even that doesn't work.

[Code for reading the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uPcN.png)

I need to filter by device id and exclude values that are greater than 30 days. If you could give me a tip on how to filter values by attribute name, that would be great.

Comment: Please follow the guidelines and don't upload pics of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Query, not Scan. Modify the below to your needs:

```
  const response = await documentClient
    .query({
      TableName: "<YourTableName>",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#pk": "<deviceId>",
        "#yr": "<date attribute name>"
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":pk": "<your device id>",
        ":yr": "<date value>"
      },
      FilterExpression: "#yr = :yr",
      KeyConditionExpression: "#pk = :pk",
    })
    .promise();
```